# Java - Am I risking compatilbity issues by using "∞" as a character?

Tags: java

I don't understand much of encoding standards such as Unicode or ASCII. I am writing a simple program that converts intervals to interval notation, for instance, [0, ∞). I don't know how to represent infinity with anything else and I definitely don't want to just use the String "infinity" in my interval notation. Here is part of my program :

```
lowerBoundCompareText = "(";
upperBoundCompareText = ")";
String infinityValue = "∞";
loopActionName = initialLoopActionName + " " + lowerBoundCompareText + upperBoundValueText + ", " + infinityValue + upperBoundCompareText;
```

Is there a better way to represent infinity, or is it fine to just use "∞" symbol?

The program works fine on my computer, but I am still worried.

Comment: How would your users actually type the infinity symbol?  ALT + <something or other>?

Comment: They don't. They have options, such as greater than some value. They enter the value and the bounds will be [value, infinity).

Comment: In any case, Java fully supports Unicode, so I don't see a problem with this, especially if it's just a display element.

Comment: That is good. Then I don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The fact that *Java* supports unicode is not of much significance here.

Comment: How do you expect the string to be displayed to the user? In a GUI widget? To a console? In a web app?  Written to a file?

Comment: Why not inf/Inf/INF ?

Comment: The string displays to the user through Eclipse SWT widget. In anycase, if a computer can run Eclipse, they most likely support this. I was just curious I guess.

Comment: Java is always supposed to deal with UTF-whatever data internally, which means that using the "infinity" character is "safe" -- it will never "go away" or get mapped to something else.  However, since source editors can do strange things, it's best to not use extended characters directly in the Java source, but instead use the Unicode escape sequence (which is apparently `\u221e`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a better way to represent infinity, or is it fine to just use "∞" symbol?

I would use the unicode constant ([221E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221e/)) to avoid any potential incompatibility issues.

```
char c = '\u221E';
System.out.println(c);
```

```
∞
```

Comment: Eh, I'm unconvinced.  Any system that supports Java must also fully support Unicode.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You may be reading the source file on a system that does not support Java.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's correct, but you also have to remember to compile the source with the correct character encoding.

Comment: @arshajii Or storing it in a version control system that doesn't support utf-8.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - The biggest problem is that the source file may be edited in a mode other than UTF8 -- this is a fairly frequent problem.  Therefore it's best to avoid having any extended characters in the source file but instead use escapes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I haven't found in the JLS where it talks about what file formats the Java compiler must support for source files (assuming the source actually comes from a file).  So I think source file incompatibility is still a potential problem (even if in practice it's not a problem).  And you'd still have the issue that not all editors that may be used to view a source file would be capable of handling this character.

Comment: If you really think it might be an issue, put a constant at the top of the program so that you can change it out if a problem occurs.  Oh, wait.  I see that the OP has already done that.

Comment: A Java identifier can include any Unicode currency character. I'm doubtful that another character set includes them all. Therefore, Java code editors and source control systems must support Unicode.

Comment: @TomBlodget Again, the facilities one may be using might not be Java-specific.